# Visual Studio 2010 Find Menu Steals Focus - Can't Wheel Scroll

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2010, if you press ctrl+f, the find menu will have focus and you will not be able to use the mouse scroll wheel to scroll in the main window. Is there a way to adjust this to allow scrolling?

In Visual Studio 2008 if you press ctrl+f, the find menu will have focus but you can still scroll in the main window. This is the behavior I want in 2k10.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can find there is no setting in VS that allows that. What I've done is added the Productivity Power Tools extension 
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/ .

Its find extension takes over for ctrl+f and allows me to scroll the text editor window even when the focus is on the find dialog.